# Cross-referencing citations with the sections they occur in [BibTex]

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I wish to know if there is a way to cross-reference the citations with the sections in which they are cited. Foe example, if a citation is given in Section 1, then in the References part, citation 1 should have a reference to section 1. Does anyone have any idea about how to do that? Another example is in this paper - [Example Paper](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Teney_Graph-Structured_Representations_for_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf)

Comment: Keyword `backref`

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the `hyperref` package with the option `backref=section`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc,author = "A and B and C", year = 3001}
@misc{uvw,author = "U and V and W", year = 4001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,
            backref=section]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{plain} % choose a suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\section{Uno}
\cite{uvw}
\section{Due}
\cite{abc}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```